# How can one test appengine/drive/google api based applications?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

There are several components involved in auth and the discovery based service api.

How can one test request handlers wrapped with decorators used from oauth2client (eg oauth_required, etc), httplib2, services and uploads?

Are there any commonly available mocks or stubs?

Comment: Ask this question with what you are trying to solve.  You mention a bunch of different products that can be used in wildly different ways but you provide very little specific to what you're working with including the actual language that you're using.

Comment: I think the OP was asking a generic question about the availability of  either pre-rolled testing frameworks or guides, rather than specific advice on building his own solution.

Comment: The second paragraph really says it all: How can one test request handlers wrapped with decorators used from oauth2client? Additionally,  httplib2 or any google api service. Not sure I can clarify any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are the mock http and request classes that the apiclient package uses for its own testing. They are in apiclient/http.py and you can see how to use them throughout the test suite.